# i want to sort list box in given order when transfer to another list box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

Here is the code

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.headerList, new MultiSelectList(Model.headerList), new { id = "AvailableGenres", size = "50", value=1,style = "height: 300px;" })</div>
<input id="btnAddAll" type="button" value=" >> " onclick="addallItems();" />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value=" > " onclick="addItem();" />
<input id="btnRemove" type="button" value=" < "  onclick="removeItem();" />
<input id="btnRemoveAll"type="button" value=" << "  onclick="removeallItems();" />
<div style="height:-1px;float:right;">
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ChosenGenres, new MultiSelectList(Model.ChosenGenres), new { id = "ChosenGenres", @class = "ChosenGenreslist", size = "50", style = "height: 300px;" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort the second list alphabetically by the option's text

```
var options = $('#ChosenGenres option');
options.sort(function (x, y) {
  return x.text > y.text;    
});
$('#ChosenGenres').empty().append(options);
```

Side note: Recommend you learn to use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://Unobtrusive_JavaScript)